# Load a file from lang dir in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

How to load a language file in all locales in Laravel (COMMON.PHP)?

```
/resources
    /lang
        /en
            test.php
        /fa
            test.php
        /fr
          test.php
        /COMMON.php
```

Answer (score 0):

In `resources/lang/` , make the language abbreviation name folder and put your language file there.

Comment: for ALL locales.